# c# richtextbox show 2 text(righ to left and left to right) file on one richtextbox

Tags: c#

I want to show 2 text file on one richtextbox.for example a.txt(text direction : right to left)and b.txt(text direction :left to right)
I use these codes:

```
   richTextBox1.LoadFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\database\\a.txt");
   string x = richTextBox1.Text;
   richTextBox1.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
   richTextBox1.LoadFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\database\\b.txt");
   richTextBox1.AppendText(x);
   richTextBox1.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
   richTextBox1.Focus();enter code here
```

but when run these codes,all lines direction in richtextbox are left to right.how can solve this problem?

Comment: Set the `richTextBox1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes`?

Comment: I use this code but all direction change

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what the issue is.  Text files do not have a direction.  Maybe clear that part up: what do you mean by text direction?  Can you post a small text snippet from each file?

Comment: for example:when  I use this code""""" richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;""""" and type in richtext box and save it "a.txt" then I use tise code""""richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;""""and type in richtext box and save it "b.txt" I want show  a from right and b form left but show both of them from left "tahnks for your help"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with `RTF` property of the `RichTextBox`.

First load the content of files `a.txt` and `b.txt` to `YourFirstTextFileString` and `YourSecondTextFileString`.

Second your code should be:

```
string rtfsource="{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1256\deff0\deflang1025{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}";
rtfsource = rtfsource + "\\ltrpar "+YourFirstTextFileString
rtfsource = rtfsource + "\\par\\rtlpar "+YourSecondTextFileString +"\\par"
rtfsource = rtfsource + "}"

// Set the rtf format to the richtextbox.
richTextBox1.RTF = rtfsource;
```

Content of the `YourFirstTextFileString` will appear Left-To-Right and `YourFirstTextFileString` will appear Right-To-Left in the `RichTextBox`.

Comment: realy thanks.this codes run correctly only change""""@"{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1256\deff0\deflang1065....."""""" thanks again

Comment: Yes . the header may be change in your content